# Button in Custom cell of table view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a button in custom cell of a tableView. The function for all the buttons are different for different row. But as i have custom cell so it does not tell which row is selected, when i press the button and it runs default function of that button. Can anyone please help me how to change the function on the click of the button. Or how to know which row button is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your button handler check the `indexPath.row` of the cell. That's how you know what cell the button is contained within.

Answer (score 1):

within your cellForRowAtIndexPath use;

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row

cell.yourbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

then create a function for your button

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    var buttonCell = sender.tag

    // do what you need
    // This will do what you need for the selected button in the cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans, i just implement it and it worked fine even without adding the target. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can tell which cell(s) is selected by calling `indexPathForSelectedRow()` or `indexPathsForSelectedRows()` methods on the table view.

Comment: I am not selecting the cell. I am only selecting the particular button from the cell.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then **@Chris Slowik**'s answer is the way to go.